# Ansible: check if Cloudflare record exists

Tags: ansible, cloudflare

Is there a way to check with Ansible cloudflare_dns module if a Cloudflare record exist?

Comment: Have you tested with [`check_mode: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks)?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε It worked, thank you! With state: absent and no record we get changed: false

Answer (score 1):

An older thread, but here's how I solved it in Ansible:

```
#
# Needs a Cloudflare API token with sufficient rights
# cf_api_token
#
# And the name of the zone for which you want to list records
# cf_zone_name
#
---
- name: Get Cloudflare zone info
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: Bearer {{ cf_api_token }}
  register: cf_zones

# This task can be very noisy when you have lots of zones
- name: Get Cloudflare id for target zone
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    cf_zone_id: '{{ item.id }}'
  loop: '{{ cf_zones.json.result }}'
  when: item.name == '{{ cf_zone_name }}'

- name: Print the zone id
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: cf_zone_id

# Example: get all CNAME records
- name: Get all CNAME records from Cloudflare
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/{{ cf_zone_id }}/dns_records?type=CNAME'
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: Bearer {{ cf_api_token }}
  register: cf_records

# Example: Loop over the output containing all the CNAMES
# and find all CNAMES pointing to somehost.somedomain.com
# This task can also be very noisy when you have lots of records
- name: Grab any CNAME records pointing to a certain host
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    cf_cname_list: '{{ cf_cname_list | default([]) + [ item.name ] }}'
  loop: '{{ cf_records.json.result }}'
  when: item.content == 'somehost.somedomain.com'

- name: Print the records found
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: cf_cname_list
```

The main reason for doing it like this is that I couldn't get the check mode to let me select e.g. all CNAME records pointing to the same host if you don't exactly know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

a simple shell script can do this

```bash
record_identifier=$(curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$CF_ZONE_ID/dns_records?name=$CF_RECORD_NAME" \
    -H "X-Auth-Email: $CF_EMAIL" \
    -H "X-Auth-Key: $CF_API_TOKEN_GLOBAL" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" |
    grep -Po '(?<="id":")[^"]*')

echo "record_identifier: $record_identifier"

if [ -z "$record_identifier" ]; then
    echo "Empty record_identifier"
    exit 1
else
    echo "record_identifier: $record_identifier"
fi
```